# Find a condition for the unilateral forward shift

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional, separable complex Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)_n$.

Let $T$ be the unilateral forward shift with $Te_n= t_n e_{n+1}$, where  $(t_n) \in \ell^{\infty}$

Let $\mathcal{K}(H)$ denote the set of compact operators acting on $H$.

Let $\pi:\mathcal{B(H)}\rightarrow\mathcal{B(H)}/\mathcal{K(H)}$ be the canonical quotient map,

Note that $\pi(T^*)= \pi(T)^*$.

Find a necessary condition on the sequence $(t_n)$ so that $\pi(T^*)\pi(T)=\pi(T)\pi(T^*)$.

I suspect that the condition will have something to do we the normality and compactness of $T$. But I'm not sure about this.

Any ideas or help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\pi$ is multiplicative, the right point of view is to look at $\pi(T^*T)=\pi(TT^*)$. Even better, looking at $\pi(T^*T-TT^*)=0$, the condition required is that $T^*T-TT^*$ is compact.

In terms of the matrix units $\{E_{kj}\}$ coming from $\{e_n\}$,
$$
T=\sum_k t_kE_{k+1,k},\qquad\qquad T^*=\sum_k\overline{t_k}\,E_{k,k+1}. 
$$
Then
$$
T^*T=\sum_k|t_k|^2\,E_{kk},\qquad\qquad TT^*=\sum_k|t_k|^2\,E_{k+1,k+1},
$$
and
$$
T^*T-TT^*=|t_1|^2\,E_{11}+\sum_{k>1}(|t_k|^2-|t_{k-1}|^2)\,E_{kk}. 
$$
This is a diagonal operator, and it is compact if and only if $\lim|t_k|^2-|t_{k-1}|^2=0$.

---

**Edit: Working on the basis elements**

$$
\langle T^*Te_n,e_m\rangle=\langle Te_n,Te_m\rangle=t_n\overline{t_m}\langle e_{n+1},e_{m+1}\rangle=\langle |t_n|^2e_n,e_m\rangle,
$$
so $T^*Te_n=|t_n|^2e_n$. For $n,m>1$,
$$
\langle TT^*e_n,e_m\rangle=\langle T\overline{t_{n-1}}e_{n-1},e_m\rangle=\langle |t_{n-1}|^2e_n,e_m\rangle.
$$
So,
$$
(T^*T-TT^*)e_1=T^*Te_1=|t_1|^2e_1,
$$
and
$$\tag{$*$}
(T^*T-TT^*)e_n=(|t_n|^2-|t_{n-1}|^2)e_n,\qquad\qquad n>1. 
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you explain further what $E_{kj}$ is? I'm still not sure what that is. Is it just a single element from the matrix $E$ built from $\{ e_n\}$? Prob not, since it's not even a sequence in that case...

Comment: Exactly as in the matrix case, $E_{kj}$ is the operator $$E_{kj}x=\langle x,e_j\rangle\,e_k.$$ In any case, the notation doesn't really matter. Just calculate $T^*T-TT^*$.

Comment: Sorry for the bother. How did you get $T^*T = \sum |t_k|^2 E_{kk}$? I kept getting $T^*T=TT^* = \sum |t_k|^2 E_{k+1,k+1} $. I have that  $\langle T^*Te_n, e_m \rangle =w_n \overline{w_m} \langle e_{n+1} , e_{m+1 } \rangle =\langle TT^*e_n, e_m \rangle$

Comment: I wrote the computation again using basis elements.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. The steps are clear now! Just one last question. To conclude that the condition is $\lim |t_k|^2- |t_{k-1}|^2=0$, why  $\lim |t_k|^2- |t_{k-1}|^2=0$ is equivalent to saying $T^*T-TT^*$ is compact?

Comment: Because $T^*T-TT^*$ is diagonal, its spectrum is $\overline{\{|t_k|^2-|t_{k-1}|^2:  \ k\}}$. Note that $(*)$ is an eigenvalue equality.